# K-Maps (Digital Logic, Computer System Architecture)

Tags: computer-architecture, digital-circuits

While i was going thru my course in Computer System Architecture (book taken Morris Mano) , I saw a question on KMaps can be solved in either of the ways but couldn't get which one to use when :-

I’m taking for an example kmaps for 3 var

```
    A’B’    A’B     AB  AB’
C’   0      1       3    2
C    4      5       7    6
```

(probably here we are taking CAB’ = 6

and below like AB’C =5 )

```
    A’B’  A’B    AB     AB’
C’   0     2      6     4
C    1     3      7     5
```

**But how do i know which one to use and when**

Comment: https://gateoverflow.in/389078/kmaps-digital-logic-self-doubt?show=389089#c389089
it is also a useful thread (same issue is answered) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct in their own way. The goal of K-map is to aid the minimization of boolean functions, it doesn't impose any rules on how it is created.

With reference to your example, if you are minimizing a function $F(C,A,B)$ then you interpret it as rows first$(MSB = C)$ and then columns $(A,B)$. If you are minimizing $F(A,B,C)$ then you interpret it as columns first $(MSBs = A,B)$ and then rows $(C)$. This is because $F(A,B,C)\neq F(C,B,A)$ for a given truth value assignment i.e. given a truth table for $F(A,B,C)$ you cant use the truth values in the same order for $F(C,B,A)$ and expect the same minimized expression. (You can easily verify this by taking up an example truth table for $(A,B,C)$ and use the same for $(C,B,A)$, and as food for thought, how to make them same).

Comment: https://gateoverflow.in/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=11215280654764166528
( Suppose given a boolean function f(a,b,c) = Σm (2, 4, 5, 7) for a mux 4:1)
in this case  , if i'm supposed to insert values of B , then i'll take the Kmap as ??

Comment: I have mentioned exactly this in my answer. If you have a different query post it as a different question.